# How to update core data model in one to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

I have one to many core data model i am looking for update New car model i.e. "Alto" under "Maruti".

[image]

```
    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let person = Person(context: context)
    person.firstName = "jjj"
    person.lastName = "sss"

    let marutiModel = Vehicals(context : context)
    marutiModel.companyName = "Maruti"

    let marutiVehical1 = CarModel(context : context)
    marutiVehical1.carModelName = "Swift"

    let marutiVehical2 = CarModel(context : context)
    marutiVehical2.carModelName = "Waganor"//later on i want to add "Alto"

    marutiModel.addToVehicalModel(marutiVehical1)
    marutiModel.addToVehicalModel(marutiVehical2)
```

I tried `setValue(` method but don't know where to put it exactly.  My requirement is to add new car model.

Comment: Please refer more idea on Core-Data: https://github.com/MakwanaRohit/iCoredata-1

Comment: @RohitMakwana i think in your example one to many update operation is not there ?

Comment: let me check and I will add if not there.

Comment: btw is my one to many connection diagram is correct ?

Comment: yes it looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Please make some change in your code. You need to use `NSSet` while adding multiple vehicles refer Sample code.

```
func update() {

    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let person = Person(context: context)
    person.firstName = "jjj"
    person.lastName = "kkkk"

    let marutiModel = Vehicals(context : context)
    marutiModel.companyName = "Maruti"

    let marutiVehical1 = CarModel(context : context)
    marutiVehical1.carModelName = "Swift"

    let altoVehical = CarModel(context : context)
    altoVehical.carModelName = "Alto"

    // add like below   
    person.vehicals =  NSSet(array: [marutiModel, marutiVehical1, altoVehical]) 

   ..... // your code for adding or update

}
```